# Mystery item broken on old Dawes. Help!

Tags: brakes, repair

I was adjusting rear brakes last night and this little thing snapped in half (see image [right]). The linear indent holds my brake cable in place and a 5mm bolt holds this in place. I guess I need to find a replacement but I have no idea where to start. Does anyone know what this might be called? Can I stillfind something like this?

Bike: Old Dawes Horizon (1990's maybe?) 
Braking system: Centre pull cantilever.

Thanks!

[image: Left. Full part taken from front (working) brakes. Right: Snapped part taken from rear brakes.]

Comment: Grooved washers are typically used to hold cables on brakes or derailleurs. Check at your LBS.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's a simple cable clamp.  A good bike shop will probably be able to scavenge one from their spare parts box and should give it to you for free or a modest price.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, it is a cable clamp. They come in a variety of styles, knowing the make and type of brake it came from would help your LBS find something that should work.